# Oracle Data Redaction

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to set up Oracle Data Redaction to eliminate some SSNs that are being pulled into our system. I tried using DBMS_REDACT.REDACT_NUM_US_SSN_F5, but that was a bit too literal -- since I'm in New England, there are a lot of SSNs with leading 0s that disappear in the numeric field the SSNs are being stored in (yes, I know, I didn't design it). I tried doing a REGEXP match, but that (predictably) only seems to work on character fields.

Does anybody know how to make it consistently return 999991234, regardless of the leading zeros (or single 0, if the position isn't filled)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_REDACT.ADD_POLICY(
 object_schema =>'schemaname', 
 object_name =>'tablename', 
 column_name =>'columnname', 
 policy_name =>'policyneme', 
 function_type =>DBMS_REDACT.REGEXP, 
 policy_description =>'Masks the last 4 digits of SSN', 
 regexp_replace_string =>'XXXXX\3', 
 regexp_position =>1, 
 regexp_occurrence =>0, 
 regexp_match_parameter =>'i', 
 expression =>'1=1', 
 regexp_pattern =>'(\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)'
);
END;
```

Try this one that delivered expression only work for some standard formats